# Rails - mongodb - new root user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'd like to create new root user in mongodb who has access to any database, any collection and perform all actions as root.
Below is my `mongoid.yml` file

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: mydb_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        user: rootuser
        password: 12345
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

I read the documentation and I've created new `rootuser`

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: 'rootuser', pwd: '12345', roles: ['root']});
```

It created the user successfully but with access to `admin` database only instead of to any database.

```
Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized (User rootuser is not authorized to access mydb_development.):
```

On the other hand when I'd like to add new root user being in `mydb_development`myrootuser

```
use mydb_development
db.createUser({user: 'rootuser', pwd: '12345', roles: ['root']});
```

I can't create new user and I get error:

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named root@mydb_development :
```

So the question is : How to add new user with root privileges and be able to use it through `mongoid.yml` ?

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this by using the `dbOwner` role instead of `root`. The `root` role  can only be used when you are on the `admin` db.

```
use admin;
db.createUser({user: 'rootuser', pwd: '12345', roles: ['root']});
```